# Not able to set the visibility of a button inside a listview programmatically

Tags: android, listview, button, android-listview, visibility

I am trying to set the visibility of a button based on a certain condition in a listview.

Context : The listview has parameters for response to a post . It contains title,description etc of the response along with a voteup button.Only the user who is the owner of the parent post should be able to see the button so that he can vote up a response.

The java part of the code where i am trying to set the visibility of the button:

```
adapter= new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, list,
                    R.layout.response_list, columns, mapping);  //response_list is the xml layout file where response parameters are defined.
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listallresponses); //listallresponses is the id of response_list layout file.

if (!parent.equals(userLoggedin)) { //"parent" is the userid of the parent post. "userLoggedin" is the current user who is viewing the parent post and its responses.
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View v = li.inflate(R.layout.response_list, null, false);
    Button upVoteButton = (Button) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.upvoteButton); //upvoteButton is the one whose visibility we are talking about.
    upVoteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The response_list.xml where i am defining the parameters for a response is below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/responseList"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="6dip" >
<!-- Other views are present here-->
<Button
  android:id="@+id/upvoteButton"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:onClick="upVoteResponse"
  android:text="VoteUp"/>
```

The problem : upvoteButton is always visible in the response list even if the user logged in is not equal to the owner of the parent post . Would like to know how i can make it work !  Thanks in advance.

*Note : My familiarity with Android is only five months . I have searched quite a bit to figure out how to make this work ,but could not succeed till now.*

Comment: do the same thing in adapter iteself, inside `getView`

Comment: Have you taken care of view recycling? Does not seem so!

Comment: @Skynet : Did you mean adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ? I have tried it  ,if yes.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain : Will read on the getView and try to implement. Will update the  post soon.

Comment: Try customizing your adapter and include the lifecycle methods of the adapter [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View v = li.inflate(R.layout.response_list, null, false);
    Button upVoteButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.upvoteButton); 
    upVoteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The view "v" & "upVoteButton" referenced here in line 2 & 3 are not visible any where. PLease note that you have inflated the view "v" and "upVoteButton" have been inflated in memory but not in User Interface.

The view and button referenced in your code are NOT AT ALL the one which you actually you want to reference.

You should not inflate any view inside your if-block, instead you must use the getView() method's parameters - View and Position to achieve your goal.

Comment: All right. I will do some reading on the getView() method.Have not used it till now.

Comment: Implemented by customizing the simpleadapter and overriding the getView() method.I am accepting this answer as it gave me the right explanation.